# removing space around components in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have a gui that keeps scrolling on the 8520 screen. I have used **setPadding(XYEdges)** and **setMargin(XYEdges)** to remove the spaces around the components on the UI but there's still space left in between these components. Are there other API calls i can make to remove spaces around components?

Comment: what is your meaning about "component" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider the following:

setPadding refers to a boundary inside the border of a field and controls how close the internal content of the field can be to the border.

setMargin refers to a boundary outside the border of a field and controls how close the field can be to an adjacent field on that edge.

BUT note that the margins of adjacent fields overlap, so that if field A has it's right margin set to 0, and right adjacent field B has it's left margin set to 20, then the two fields will still be placed no closer than 20 pixels apart.

i.e. you have to take into account the margins set for the edges of all adjacent fields.

Returning to padding, the same applies for managers if you set their internal padding. This will determine how close to the inside of the manager's border an included field can be placed.

Somewhere in the blackberry documentation and/or support forum, there is a document explaining this pictorially, I just can't find my link to it right now, but will post it here when I find it again.

Comment: Here is the reference to the relevent page in the UI guidelines, also read the pages before and after: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Margin_1578863_11.jsp